# Rewrite Rule for an URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to do a rewrite rule to replace this url https://example.com/user.php?user=1000 to **https://example.com/1000**

If I wanted to rewrite the url to https://example.com/user/1000 I would have done that:

```
RewriteRule ^(user)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?u=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but how to do it without the user?

Here is my htaccess which is already managing the https redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but in this case user.php and user parameter will be static.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```